# How to use imported fonts in a VUE project?

Tags: html, css, vue.js, fonts, font-face

I'm developing my first project of vue and following the different examples and the official documentation I can't solve a mistake when using the imported fonts in my project locally.[image: console error]

in my  tag I import the font that I want to use in the component and then I refer to it when using it and it returns the error that I attached in the image

```
<style scooped>

@font-face {
    font-family: 'RalewayRegular';
    src: local('RalewayRegular'),
    url(../../fonts/Raleway-Regular.ttf) format('truetype');
    font-style: normal;
}

body {
  font-family: 'RalewayRegular';
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: baseline;
}

.menu {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline;
}

.nav-item {
  padding: 25px;
  position: relative;
}

.nav-link:hover {
  color: #666B74;
}

.menu-link-toggle {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  width: max-content;

}

a {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #D53865;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 30%;
  height: 3px;
  bottom: 30%;
  left: 35%;
  background: #D53865;
  visibility: hidden;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: .25s linear;
}

a:hover:before,
a:focus:before {
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scaleX(1);

}

.added {
  display: none;
}


</style>
```

Is there someone who is used to using VUE who can help me and tell me what my mistake is?
Thank you in advance for your time and help

Comment: Looks like a webpack issue. You probably need a config. Check this article `https://chriscourses.com/blog/loading-fonts-webpack`

Comment: Have you tried using CDN or Google Font API?

Comment: @BhaveshLohana I haven't tried because I need a font not available in google fonts

Comment: @ZdravkoPernikov THANK YOU SO MUCH!! I've been walking around for a couple of days and I couldn't find a solution!! It's perfect, if you answer me with the same link I'll validate your answer!

Comment: @javascript110899, glad I could help buddy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a webpack issue. You probably need a config.
[Check out this article](https://chriscourses.com/blog/loading-fonts-webpack)